# R: What is an efficient way to recode variables? How do I prorate means?

Tags: r, statistics, recode

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of how I would go about recoding multiple variables with the same rules. I have the following df `bhs1`:

```
structure(list(bhs1_1 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 1, 2), bhs1_2 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 1, 1), bhs1_3 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 2, 2), bhs1_4 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 1, 1, 1), bhs1_5 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 2, 2), bhs1_6 = c(NA, 
1, NA, 2, 1, 2), bhs1_7 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 2, 1), bhs1_8 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 2, 2), bhs1_9 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1), bhs1_10 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 1, 2, 2), bhs1_11 = c(NA, 2, NA, 2, 2, 1), bhs1_12 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 1, 1), bhs1_13 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 2, 2), bhs1_14 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 1, 1), bhs1_15 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 2, 2), bhs1_16 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 2, 2), bhs1_17 = c(NA, 2, NA, 2, 2, 1), bhs1_18 = c(NA, 
1, NA, 1, 2, 1), bhs1_19 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 1, 2), bhs1_20 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

There are two transformation rules, for half of the data set, e.g.,:

```
(bhs1_2, bhs1_4, bhs1_7, bhs1_9, bhs1_11, bhs1_12, bhs1_14, bhs1_16, bhs1_17, 
bhs1_18, bhs1_20) 
(if_else(1, 1, 0))

and 

(bhs1_1, bhs1_3, bhs1_5, bhs1_6, bhs1_8, bhs1_10, bhs1_13, 
bhs1_15, bhs1_19)
(if_else(2, 1, 0))
```

Is there an elegant way to write code to meet this use case? If so, can someone please point me in the right direction and/or provide me with a sample?

Comment: How do you want to treat `NA` in your data?

Comment: @MKR, `NA` should stay as `NA`. @akrun, no, only values of 1 and 2 should be in there. Anything else will either be `NA` or an error, which will need to be removed prior to running this recode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
case1 <- vars(bhs1_2, bhs1_4, bhs1_7, bhs1_9, bhs1_11, bhs1_12, bhs1_14, bhs1_16, bhs1_17, 
  bhs1_18, bhs1_20) 
case2 <- vars(bhs1_1, bhs1_3, bhs1_5, bhs1_6, bhs1_8, bhs1_10, bhs1_13, 
  bhs1_15, bhs1_19)
result <- df %>%
  mutate_at(case1, ~ (. == 1) * 1L) %>%
  mutate_at(case2, ~ (. == 2) * 1L)
```

Note - I skipped the ifelse statement - I'm just testing for your condition, then converted the `TRUE`/`FALSE` responses to numbers by multiplying by 1.  I'm also not sure how you want NAs to be handled, but this is ignoring them.

If you aren't familiar with the pipe operator (`%>%`), it takes the result of the previous function, and sets it as the first argument of the next function.  It's designed to improve code legibility by avoiding lots of function nesting.

Comment: Very first one to provide answer and it's really good to see that you have mentioned note about not considering `NA`.

Comment: Thanks for this. When you say you're "just testing" for my condition, what do you mean? When you say the it is "ignoring NAs", do you mean it will just skip over them? If I wanted to recode NAs, (or another value), how would I handle that?

Comment: By "just testing" for your condition, I mean that I'm not using `ifelse`. 
 Yes, this is skipping over the NA's.  If you wanted to recode them, you need to test that using `is.na(variable_name)`.  How you would incorporate this depends on what you want to replace them with.

Comment: @MelissaKey, why did the values turn from number to TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: The trick here is that if you convert TRUE/FALSE to a number, TRUE -> 1 and FALSE -> 0.  So I performed a test - (. == 1) (is the number equal to 1, which returns TRUE/FALSE.  Instead of wrapping this in an Ifelse statement to get a number (which I could have done), I multiply it by 1, which forces R to convert the boolean values to numbers

Comment: @MelissaKey, thanks so much. So (just to be clear as I can feel my training wheels rattling), instead of `mutate_at(case2, ~ (. == 2) * 1L)` we could have written `mutate_at(case2, ~ (if_else(2, 1, 0, missing = NULL)))`?

Comment: Not quite.  The first argument to `if_else` has to evaluate to a boolean value (TRUE/FALSE).  2 evaluates to be 2.  It is equivalent to `mutate_at(case2, ~ (if_else(. == 2, 1, 0, missing = NULL)))`

Answer (score 2):

We can create the column names of interest, then convert to binary (`as.integer`) from the logical expression

```
case1 <- c("bhs1_2", "bhs1_4", "bhs1_7", "bhs1_9", "bhs1_11", "bhs1_12", 
   "bhs1_14", "bhs1_16", "bhs1_17", "bhs1_18", "bhs1_20") 

case2 <-  c("bhs1_1", "bhs1_3", "bhs1_5", "bhs1_6", "bhs1_8", 
   "bhs1_10", "bhs1_13", "bhs1_15", "bhs1_19")
library(magrittr)
df1 %<>%
    mutate_at(vars(case1), funs(as.integer(.==1 ))) %<>%
    mutate_at(vars(case2), funs(as.integer(.==2)))

df1
# A tibble: 6 x 20
#  bhs1_1 bhs1_2 bhs1_3 bhs1_4 bhs1_5 bhs1_6 bhs1_7 bhs1_8 bhs1_9 bhs1_10
#   <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>   <int>
#1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
#2      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1       1
#3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
#4      1      0      1      1      0      1      1      1      0       0
#5      0      1      1      1      1      0      0      1      1       1
#6      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1       1
# ... with 10 more variables: bhs1_11 <int>, bhs1_12 <int>, bhs1_13 <int>,
#   bhs1_14 <int>, bhs1_15 <int>, bhs1_16 <int>, bhs1_17 <int>, bhs1_18 <int>,
#   bhs1_19 <int>, bhs1_20 <int>
```

---

Or an efficient option would be to use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, (case1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(x == 1 )),
  .SDcols = case1
      ][, (case2) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(x == 2)), 
  .SDcols = case2][]
```

NOTE This doesn't assume that all the values are of the same

Comment: [#84](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/483627/who-is-the-user-with-highest-combined-reputation-from-all-stack-exchange-sites) and still going strong

Comment: Sure. Why did you have to include `!is.na(.)`??

Comment: Thank you for this. What is does the `.==1` and `.==2` mean in this context?

Comment: @AtanasJanackovski  The `.` represents each column value that is selected within the `mutate_at`.   Instead of that, you can also have anonymous function `function(x) x== 1`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. If I wanted to do these conversions to a df in situ, how would I do this? That is, I only want to apply this conversion to certain columns within a df.

Comment: @AtanasJanackovski  I also updated the answer in the other question

Comment: @AtanasJanackovski  Just like we specified `case1`, `case2`, create a vector of column names and apply the function with in `mutate_at`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very fast base R way of doing this as below:

```
case1=c("bhs1_10", "bhs1_11", "bhs1_12", "bhs1_13", "bhs1_14", "bhs1_15","bhs1_16", "bhs1_17", "bhs1_18", "bhs1_19", "bhs1_20")  

case2=c("bhs1_1", "bhs1_3", "bhs1_5", "bhs1_6", "bhs1_8", "bhs1_10", "bhs1_13", "bhs1_15", "bhs1_19")

dat[case1]=abs(dat[case1]-2)
dat[case2]=dat[case2]-1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This seems super simple for this use case. Do need to load the df first? Sorry, haven't tried this yet... Just wondering.

Comment: `dat` is your `df` ie data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

An simple `ifelse` can be helpful considering OP wants `NA` to be converted based on specified rules:

```
case1 = c("bhs1_2", "bhs1_4", "bhs1_7", "bhs1_9", "bhs1_11", "bhs1_12",
          "bhs1_14", "bhs1_16", "bhs1_17", "bhs1_18", "bhs1_20")

case2 = c("bhs1_1", "bhs1_3", "bhs1_5", "bhs1_6", "bhs1_8", "bhs1_10",
          "bhs1_13", "bhs1_15", "bhs1_19")


df[case1] = ifelse(!is.na(df[case1]) & df[case1]==1,1,0)
df[case2] = ifelse(!is.na(df[case2]) & df[case2]==2,1,0)

#Test solution
df[1:7]
#   bhs1_1 bhs1_2 bhs1_3 bhs1_4 bhs1_5 bhs1_6 bhs1_7
# 1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
# 2      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
# 3      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
# 4      1      0      1      1      0      1      1
# 5      0      1      1      1      1      0      0
# 6      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

**Updated:**If `NA` to be left as is then solution can be:

```
df[case1] = ifelse(df[case1]==1,1,0)
df[case2] = ifelse(df[case2]==2,1,0)


df[1:7]
#   bhs1_1 bhs1_2 bhs1_3 bhs1_4 bhs1_5 bhs1_6 bhs1_7
# 1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
# 2      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
# 3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
# 4      1      0      1      1      0      1      1
# 5      0      1      1      1      1      0      0
# 6      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

Comment: Thanks @MKR. Actually, I wanted the `NAs` to stay as is. Apologies, I should have stated this more clearly. How would I do this keeping `NAs` as is?

Comment: I'll modify my answer to exclude checking for NA.

Comment: Thanks @MKR—truly appreciated.